# Android - Align child images inside Viewpager at the top

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm new at making android apps, so sorry for my noob'ness in advance.

I just made an image slider using Viewpager in Android Studio, the first image is aligned properly at the top, but the child images are not, they are almost centered. I couldn't find the solution of this problem on the web and i've been stuck at it for more than an hour.

In the layout xml files. I have tried to align it in the viewpager element, i've tried to align it with in the ImageView element (but this seems to only work for the first image), and in java i've tried to align it with imageView.setBaseline(0) but nothing worked. I also looked at the functions of the imageView class in java but i can't find a function for this other then setBaseline.

I can probably solve it by fixing the height of the viewpager element to the image heights, but i find that an ugly solution.

The relevant code is given below:

content_main.xml :

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

swipe_layout.xml :

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />
```

The function that creates the imageView in java:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout, container, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    imageView.setImageResource(image_resources[position]);
    imageView.setBaseline(0);
    container.addView(item_view);
    return item_view;
}
```

Comment: please provide whole XML file and java code

Answer (score 0):

Use TabLayout

XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#ff5722"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

And java

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(vpPager);
for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {     
    tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(//yourIcon//);}
```